# Offline map for a web application

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps, webserver

I am trying to create a web application in which you should see a map and click in different spots to do things. The problem right now is that it is an offline application, the clients and the server are not connected to the internet so I can not access Google´s or OpenStreetMap´s servers to get the maps.

Now the problem: I don't know how to create a map with no internet conection. I've seen some ideas but all of them are paid or does not meet our requirements. Those requirements are that we have to show all of Spain and be able to zoom in to areas of around 10-20 square meters, maybe a little bit more, satellite style view would be appreciated but its not a must have thing, just a nice thing to have.
With that zoom level I know downloading the tiles as pngs would require a lot of space so the best thing would be to have a rendering server with svg data.

I´ve read that its possible to cache the maps with openlayers but on restart that data is lost, I saw is that it is possible to download data with Mobile Atlas Creator but it does not allow me to download all of Spain and the zoom level is not enough. I also tried the rendering server with
GeoServer but I don't know where to download the maps for ir since the osm format from openmaps is not supported. The last thig I´ve looked at is this: [Using OpenStreetMap offline](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Using_OpenStreetMap_offline) but I'm not sure how to do it.

And the question: Does anyone know how I could do this? Is my approach right or is there a better way to do this?

Some extra info: I'm a junior developer so I'm a little lost with this, also I'm using html, CSS and JavaScript for the client and the server is a node.js express server. Also, I know the rendering server would consume a lot of resources but we have a server with 16 cores/32 threads and 64GB of RAM so, I think that should be enough, storage is not a problem, we can upgrade it, and it runs OpenSuse Leap 15.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, welcome to SO! Questions like yours are likely to remain unanswered a SO is specifically meant to help people with programming issues (code), take the [tour]. However, maybe this [page](https://www.gibbard.me/openstreetmap/) will get you a bit further serving OpenStreetMaps.

Comment: You talking about offline maps and a server at the same time, something don`t adding up.

Comment: oh, thanks @RenevanderLende i didnt know that, I saw similar questions here so i thougth it would be ok.

Comment: @BR75 maybe I should say it has no internet conection rather than offline. This server serves users in the local network witch has no access to the internet

Comment: You can totally use Openlayers to do this. We have a complete offline Android Application using Openlayers, no background tile map though, just shapes. Never used openstreetmap offline but you probably will not able to find any high res satellite tiles for free (commercial use). So you will have to buy some. Maptiler offer these but there is no price tag for the high res ones. on your server you would run a geoserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use this for the map instead of the OSM layer you use to create an online map:

```
const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'imgs/sat_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' // Route to the tiles
      }),
});
```

I downloaded the tiles with this tool: [GMapCatcher](https://github.com/heldersepu/GMapCatcher).
It lets you download different types of tiles (Including satellite). It needs a bit of tweaking to get the correct ones cause it does not use OSM by default but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I face a similar case but how did you manage to use GMapCatcher, because the GUI seems not working, and the source code also has some problems with the packages, I guess due to python 2.7, I tried to run download.py it with 2.7.18 and didn't work.

Comment: What problem do you have exactly? you see gray tiles? if the problem is that go to settings>ChangeTheme and try changing the map service. For satellite I use Virtual Earth.

Comment: In the GUI I can not find any place of the earth, I get a message "Place not found", did you try it with windows 11 or with another os? I suspect that at least for the GUI windows 11 not working (also in the documentation till windows 10 is mentioned).

Comment: Well, i never used that function but I found that you have to introduce coordinates, for example, "41.649821,-0.887748" takes you to Zaragoza in Spain (without "). To get the coordinates you can search a place in google maps, then click the place, not the marks on google, just a road or something like that, at the bottom it will show the coordinates, in PC at least. And yes, I am using windows 11 and it works fine.